# How do I pass default JVM args in a Gradle script while allowing variables to be expanded?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've got the following in my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.20"
    application
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dlog_dir=MY_APP_HOME/log")
}

tasks.withType<CreateStartScripts>().configureEach {
    doLast {
        windowsScript.text = windowsScript.text.replace("MY_APP_HOME", "%APP_HOME%")
        unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replace("MY_APP_HOME", "\$APP_HOME")
    }
}
```

I've discovered that the unix shell script wraps my JVM args in single and double quotes.

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dlog_dir=$APP_HOME/log"'
```

Because of this, the variable `$APP_HOME` is not expanded and the log dir for my application is literally "$APP_HOME/log".

I cannot find any way to prevent this behavior. How can I get the variable to be expanded properly?

Comment: Separately, I don't know if your "/log" will always work on Windows given the backslash issue. If you're not sure either, perhaps the safest and easiest thing to do is just pass `%APP_HOME%` to Kotlin and deal with changing directory inside the safety of Kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your placeholder `"MY_APP_HOME"` with the application home directory in a JVM argument using<sup>1</sup>:

```
tasks.withType<CreateStartScripts>().configureEach {
    doLast {
        windowsScript.writeText(
            windowsScript.readText().replace("MY_APP_HOME", "%APP_HOME%")
        unixScript.writeText(
            unixScript.readText().replace("MY_APP_HOME", "'\$APP_HOME'")
        )
    }
}
```

I have used Kotlin's `writeText` and `readText` functions as the `text` operator on a `File` is only in Groovy, I believe.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note this is guaranteed by an integration test in the Gradle project (written in Groovy): see [GitHub](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/27736f787ed3005acc2c777eb8f0c85e66dcc860/subprojects/plugins/src/integTest/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/ApplicationPluginIntegrationTest.groovy#L465).

The test code has two extra backslashes in its definition of the text to replace in the unix script: it writes `"'\\\$APP_HOME'"`. Those extra backslashes are there because the test build file code that contains this is itself wrapped in triple quotes.

Comment: I should have updated the question, but I am basically already doing this but with an extension function I created instead of calling `readText()` and `writeText()` directly. This does not change the fact that the unix script template wraps the `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` value with a single quote, preventing variable expansion.

Comment: Try the answer. It's not quite the same as yours. It anticipates that issue, as guaranteed by the Gradle test.

Comment: I see. It looks like the missing part was the extra single quotes around `\$APP_HOME`. That does seem to have worked

Comment: Yes, it anticipates how the variable is wrapped in quotes within the script. We are at the mercy of Gradle's implementation of the script here, hence the importance of the test. It gives some kind of assurance it's seen as a feature of a kind and it's less likely to break on a random version change.